# MemoryError vs OverflowError for very large integers in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer-overflow

When testing the limits of how Python 3 handles very large integers (much too large to actually allocate), I noticed that up to `2**69175290276410818320`, a `MemoryError` is raised:

```py
>>> 1 << 69175290276410818320
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

whereas when you request one more bit above that, you get an `OverflowError`:

```py
>>> 1 << 69175290276410818321
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: too many digits in integer
```

This change point is at `7*sys.maxsize + sys.maxsize//2 - 231` (for 64-bit Python 3.8.6), which seems kind of arbitrary.

From the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OverflowError) (emphasis mine):

> *exception* OverflowError
>
> Raised when the result of an arithmetic operation is too large to be represented. This cannot occur for integers (which would rather raise MemoryError than give up). **However, for historical reasons, OverflowError is sometimes raised for integers that are outside a required range.** Because of the lack of standardization of floating point exception handling in C, most floating point operations are not checked.

My question: what are these historical reasons and how did this particular range come about?

Comment: How many systems have you tested and how many different versions?

Comment: Just the one. I understand the "required range" mentioned in the docs may be different on different systems, but having more samples of it doesn't really elucidate these historical reasons I'm interested in.

Comment: Divide by 15 to get the number of digits in [base `2**15`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b05e9b63fcfcd4bd7a6434fa9f9a7028d12f91c4/Objects/longobject.c#L2227-L2228), then it looks *less* arbitrary :-)

Comment: More info [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Include/longintrepr.h#L11).